# How to export objects with names using Illustrator CC 2014

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, cc-2014

I've tried several scripts and they all appear broken or do not work properly.

I need a method to export objects with the object names as their file names – like `tree.jpg` or `location.png`.

The only solution I've found thus far is [Layer Exporter](http://www.dehats.com/illustrator-layer-exporter/). However, this option trims the edges of the images and does not support @2x sizing. Therefore it's not a very good solution.

[image: Layer Exporter trims so much]

I can add transparent boxes inside of items like this but I think that this way is wrong.

Also, in CC 2014 the batch renaming of items is broken – it replaces item name with selected format. To avoid this issue you can install [dev version](https://github.com/davidderaedt/Illustrator-Layer-Exporter/blob/master/bin/archives/LayerExporter-2.1.0-dev.zxp) of this extension.

I tried also this options:

- [Export layers as png files from Illustrator in multiple resolutions!](http://www.arcticmill.com/2012/08/export-layers-as-png-files-from-illustrator-in-multiple-resolutions.html) by Arcticmill – this script can export only layers or sublayers with `#` or `%` in their names. I have a lot of objects and do not want to convert them into sublayers.
- [MultiExporter](https://github.com/mericson/illustrator-scripts/blob/master/MultiExporter-v2.jsx) has “Export Layers” → “Selected items' layers” in UI but falls into error `Error: an Illustrator error occurred: 1346458189 ('MRAP')` so I don't know the result of this action.
- There is also a [MultiExporter fork](https://github.com/thierryc/illustrator-scripts/blob/wip-2.0.1/MultiExporter-v2.jsx) by thierryc with PSD export and multisize that includes @2x export but it has a similar problem.
- [Layer Export](http://www.metaphorical.net/note/on/layer_export) by Metamorphical also exports only top-level layers
- [Export Layers as Images](http://js4ai.blogspot.ru/2010/06/export-layers-as-images.html) by John Wundes just does nothing in CC 2014.

**Are there any automated options to export images retaining object names and supporting @2x sizing?**

Comment: I've edited the question a bit to be less spam oriented. I hope you don't mind. I think the issue was more about phrasing than the inclusion of the link.

Comment: Adding links to other scripts you've tried would also be helpful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16267/discussion-between-grawl-and-scott).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was easy to find this feature just with googing `illustrator assets generator` and finding [this](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/companion-videos-for-inspire/generate-global-css-properties-and-image-assets-from-illustrator-cc/) on Adobe TV.

### Just in short: CSS Properties pane.

- If you want to export a raster image (`png` for example) you need to add your object into a **symbol**. Sometimes I was need to rename an object after creating a symbol. Strange.
- Regular size `@1x` value is `72` ppi
- Double  size `@2x` value is `144` ppi
- `css` file exports always
- You can place your objects into separate artboard to export them with absolute positions based on top left artboard corner. Useful when you need to create something dynamic with `hover` and `.active` (pseudo-)classes.